# Log work for a given issue using JIRA SDK

Tags: ruby, jira-rest-api

I am using [JIRA Ruby SDK](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby) for JIRA REST API. I am trying to create to log work for a specific issue with this code:

```
projects = client.Project.all
issue = client.Issue.find("13921")
w = issue.worklogs.build
w.timeSpentSeconds = "12000"
```

However i have got this error:

```
method_missing': undefined methodtimeSpentSeconds=' for
#JIRA::Resource::Worklog:0x007f831db3f360 (NoMethodError) from jira.rb:33:in
```

Thanks!